# How does ~ distribute over parentheses?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

In my recent Discrete Math final exam, we had a question where I thought the answer was false but apparently it is true. It is the following:

$$((\forall x)P(x)) \rightarrow  ((\forall y) Q(y))) \equiv (((\exists y) \sim Q(y) \rightarrow (\sim(\forall x)P(x)))$$

Clearly, this is an application of the definition of implication and I knew this, *but* I thought that the solution was false since the ~ in 
$$(\sim(\forall x)P(x)))$$ 
should not distribute into the P(x) since I thought that 
$$(\sim(\forall x)P(x)))$$
and 
$$(\sim(\forall x) \sim P(x)))$$

are different.

I'm thinking its missing an extra pair of parens:

$$((\forall x)P(x)) \rightarrow  ((\forall y) Q(y))) \equiv (((\exists y) \sim Q(y) \rightarrow (\sim((\forall x)P(x))))$$

Am I right here?

Comment: $(∃y)∼Q(y)$ is equivalent to $∼(∀x)Q(x)$.

Comment: Thus, the RHS is equivalent to $∼(∀x)Q(x) \to ∼(∀x)P(x)$. Now, consider [Contraposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition).

Comment: The *negation* signe does **not** "distribute".

Comment: The only real question is one of precedence, i.e., one of *convention*, that is whether for a binary operator $\circ$ (such as $\land, \lor,\to$) we interprete $\sim A\circ B$ as $\sim(A\circ B)$ or $(\sim A)\circ B$. -- Just like we *agree* (for simplicity) that $a+b\cdot c$ is to be interpreted as $a+(b\cdot c)$ and not as $(a+b)\cdot c$. The purpose of such conventions is only to save writing a few parentheses in one of the two cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your basic problem here is that you're misunderstanding the structure of the formula $(\forall x)P(x)$, and this leads you to misunderstand its negation.

- $P(x)$ is a formula.
- $(\forall x)P(x)$ is a formula.
- $(\forall x)$ alone **is not a formula** -- it's just a collection of symbols that can become *part of* a formula if you put a formula behind it.

The negation symbol *only ever applies to an entire formula*. It is therefore not possible to negate $(\forall x)$ by itself -- that would mean nothing! So when we write $\sim (\forall x)P(x)$ what you're negating is the entire formula $(\forall x)P(x)$.

Semantically $(\forall x)P(x)$ means, "everything has the $P$ property".

The negation of this is $\sim(\forall x)P(x)$, which means "it is NOT the case that everything has the $P$ property", or in other words "there is something that does *not* have the $P$ property".

I suspect you were envisaging like $(\sim \forall x)$ meaning "for only some of the $x$", but that's not how the symbolism works.

Comment: Thanks! This really helps... if only I knew it for the exam :p

Comment: @ylun.ca: I just noticed that you wrote "discrete math" which suggests you're in a CS program. In computer-science jargon we would say that $\sim$ and $(\forall x)$ both behave like _unary operators_ in the syntax of logic. A lot of this gets easier to grasp by considering the abstract syntax trees (which mathematical logicians tend to underplay).

Comment: Thanks yea thinking about it this way makes more sense. I always considered the $$\forall$$ to be some sort of function. Clearly that was a mislead assumption by me though

Comment: @ylun.ca: As far as the $x$ is concerned it is better to think of $(\forall x)$ as a kind of _variable declaration_ with a scope consisting of the formula it applies to. Or, if you know a programming language that has anonymous functions (lambda expressions), $(\forall x)$ is syntactically quite similar to an anonymous function heading declaring $x$ as the name of a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the two statements are equivalent.  The statement ($a \implies b$) is equivalent to its contrapositive statement ($\sim b \implies \sim a$). It's just that in your problem, the two negations $\sim b$ and $\sim a$ are expressed differently.  One way to write "negation of $(\forall x, P(x))$" is "$\sim (\forall x, P(x))$.  A second way is to write "$\exists x, \sim P(x)$".